# Deleting row from android SQLite database corrupts entries after deleted row

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Hi everyone I am fairly new to android development and have been trying to learn how to use SQL with android. I have been working with the example code from here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

I have been able to get everything working like I want it except for the delete row function. When I delete a row the data in the rows below it become corrupt and/or out  of sync with the id column. I have been looking at examples and goggling it for the last two days but just can not find a answer so I hope one of you can help. Below is a simple example of what is happening. Let me know if I need to post any more info, any help is greatly appreciated.[Diagram of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfsRh.png)

```
public Integer deleteContact (Integer id)
{
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
  return db.delete("contacts",
           "id = ? ",
          new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });


}
```

Comment: Please post your selection and output function also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The results of the diagram are correct. Also the code is correct.

If you have got:

```
ID | Value
----------
1  | a
2  | b   <---- delete this
3  | c
```

the result will be:

```
ID | Value
----------
1  | a
3  | c
```

So the row with the id 3 has still the value c.
And if you run a query which selects the row with ID 2, the app might crash, because the returned Cursor does not point to a row.
If such a case is not handled, the app might crash.

Comment: I just tested it again. Going by your example my results are 1 | a , 2 | c . Seems like the id is not being deleted but I am not sure why.

Comment: Are your sure you are Logging the ID and not the Column number? Could you post the rest of you code?

Comment: oberflansch You are sort of correct The id I was looking at is the position from the list view

Comment: oberflansch You are sort of correct The id I was looking at is the position from the list view. The database is working correctly. I changed the code that displays each contacts data, to pull the data based on the name and not the id an now everything is working as expected. Thanks for your help everyone

Answer (score 0):

I checked you diagram, and want to tell that firstly your delete operation of row 2 should also delete it's all row values, even id. then proceeds, and Tutorial Points is having good example.

**According to your question:**
Before deletion:

```
1-a

2-b

3-c

4-d
```

After deletion of 2nd row it should have:

```
1-a

3-c

4-d
```